# Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A0047 (CTL_E_DISKNOTREADY)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am facing a problem when I want to run a published website it shows error 0x800A0047:

> DirectShow: The function attempted to access a file when the disk was not ready.

Comment: Its a clear error - you have a problem with your disk !

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is on your drive, not in your website/application.

**Cause:** For the specified drive, either there is no disk or the drive door is open.

**To correct this error**

1. Check the specified drive and insert a disk if necessary.
2. Close the drive door.

Referred from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/misc/disk-not-ready

This may help you!

Answer (score -1):

The problem occurs when you build a project or application in a 32 bit machine and install the published on a 64 bit machine. To solve this problem Go to IIS and then open Application Pools and right click on your project and select advance settings. From the Advanced Setting window and make Enable 32-bit Application True when previously it was false. Then see the output.. Have a good day !!